# How can I convert a string to a string literal for regex

Tags: c#, regex

I want to do some regex.match by building the pattern dynamically. The following code is not working. I was wondering how can I convert the string "^[ABCDEFG][ABCDEFG]$" to @"^[ABCDEFG][ABCDEFG]$" and use it for regex.

Thanks

```
static string Convert(string s)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            if (s[i].Equals('N'))
            {
                sb.Append("[ABCDEFG]");
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(s[i]);
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string seq = "CA";
        Regex re = new Regex(Convert("^NN$"));
        if (re.Match(seq).Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("match");
        }



        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: What "string literial issue"? What is the problem?

Comment: @"^[ABCDEFG]$" vs "^[ABCDEFG]$"

Comment: Huh? You really need to be more explicit in your question about what you are trying to do.

Comment: "The following code is not working"  This is the most worthless statement in programming.   You really should describe how its not working.  Compile error?  Runtime fault?  Behavior different than expected? (then, what did you expect, and what did you actually see?)

Comment: A *verbatim* string can be defined in C# by prefixing a string literal with `@`, e.g. `@"I don't need to escape this: \ "`, if that's what you mean. But *what* is going wrong?

Comment: What do you get and what do you expect to get?

Comment: Explain "The following code is not working". What is the issue you are seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A verbatim string (string *literal* prefixed with a `@`) is only sytactic sugar to allow simpler file system access and regular expression writing, because in verbatim strings the character `\` isn't treated as an escape character. That way you don't have to write `"\\\\\\.\\\\"` to match the string `"\.\"` in a regex but only `@"\\\.\\"` which is less prone to error because counting the backslashes becomes easier as their number decreases.

The following example will prove that verbatim strings are no different from normal ones:

```
public class Program
{
    public string GetString(bool verbatim)
    {
        if(verbatim)
        {
            return @"this is a test";
        }
        else
        {
            return "this is a test";
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var verbatim = GetString(true);
        var normal = GetString(false);

        // should print 'true', if I'm not mistaken, because of string interning
        Console.WriteLine("Reference equals:" + ReferenceEquals(verbatim, normal));

        // will definitely print 'true'
        Console.WriteLine("Equals:" + verbatim.Equals(normal));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are building a Regex that accepts characters A-G, but your input string contains a "U".

Comment: OK, in this case you will have to define "not working"

Comment: @Mavershang: A typo? Then it sounds that you haven't shown the code that you actually use, but typed in some other code? If that is the case, then it's impossible to tell from your question what's wrong with the code that you are actually using...

Comment: With CA instead of UA it works fine for me too.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the code, it works just fine.

It creates a regular expression that matches two characters in the range A to G.

With the string "UA" it won't write the message "match".

If you change the string to for example "BA", it will write the message.

Answer (score 0):

Strings `"^[ABCDEFG][ABCDEFG]$"` and `@"^[ABCDEFG][ABCDEFG]$"` are identical, there is nothing to convert.

`@` only says to C# compiler that the following string literal won't have any escape sequences and should take `\` as `\`, not as beginning of an escape sequence.

Therefore:

- `"Hello"` == `@"Hello"`
- `"^[ABCDEFG][ABCDEFG]$"` == `@"^[ABCDEFG][ABCDEFG]$"`

but:

- `"Foo \n"` != `@"Foo \n"`

while

- `"Foo \\n"` == `@"Foo \n"`

NB: Your code is OK and should work as expected.